# How to change package name in Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, apk

Recently i create my first app and the create an apk file to upload on goolge play. after uploading google saied uploading is failed because :

```
Upload failed
 You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK    in release mode. Learn more about signing.
You need to use a different package name because "com.jirbo.unitytest" already exists in Google Play.
```

so my question is how to i change `com.jirbo.unitytest` to my company package name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

the problem is i import `Unity3D` [AdColony Plugin](http://www.adcolony.com) and this plugin has it's own Android XML manifest. so even i change Bundle Identifier in unity it's use Adcolony. so my package name created by `com.jirbo.unitytest` bundle identifier and in Google play this package already exists. for solving this i copy and paste my own Bundlie identifier in Unity Player settings and in `Adcolony` XML manifest.

Answer (score 6):

1. Press Control + Shift + B or (Command Shift + B, MacOSX) to show the build setting dialog

[image]

2. Select Android on the left;
3. Click "Player Settings" Button
4. In the inspector, scroll down to Other Settings, change the Bundle identifier there.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to File->Build Settings->Player Settings->Other Settings. In identification settings change Bundle Identifier to "com.yourcompanyname.projectname".